# How we can add more than $subcategory_id in this query

Tags: php, mysql

My ajax File  where get term_id in checkbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Checkboxes click function
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function(){
var arr=[];

jQuery("input:checked").each(function(){

arr.push($(this).val());

});
 // alert(arr);

jQuery.get("<?=  bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template_classifiedstheme/productBySubCategory.php", { termId: $(this).val()},function(data){
         // alert(data);

     jQuery("#result").show();
     jQuery("#result").html(data);
});


    // Here we check which boxes in the same group have been selected
    // Get the current group from the class
    var group = $(this).attr("class");
    var checked = [];

    // Loop through the checked checkboxes in the same group
    // and add their values to an array
    $('input[type="checkbox"].' + group + ':checked').each(function(){
        checked.push($(this).val());
    });

    //refreshData(checked, group);
});

// function refreshData($values, $group){
      // alert("You've requested: " + $values + " from the group " + $group);
// }

});
```

MY php code  for get term_id in post value

```
foreach ($childCatID as $kid)

{

$childCatName = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name,slug, term_id FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$kid");


echo '<li><label class="lab_brand">

   <span id="sp_brand">

<input type="checkbox" rel="brand" id="input_chk" value="'.$childCatName->term_id.'" onclick="getValue(this.id)" />

</span>

<a href="'.get_term_link($childCatName->slug, 'category').'">'.$childCatName->name.'</a>

</label>

</li>';
   }
echo'</ul>

</div>';
```

MY ajax file for get term id by this query

```
$subcategory_id=$_GET['termId'];

$querystr = "SELECT *

FROM wp_terms

INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id

INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = wpr.object_id

WHERE taxonomy =  'category'

AND p.post_type =  'post'

AND p.post_status =  'publish'

AND wp_terms.term_id = $subcategory_id
```

but we can find only one term_id

when i checked more than one checkbox
only one value get in termId

Comment: What are you trying to do??

Comment: I don't see a question. Please be more specific

Comment: You can probably add to the Where clause but you would have to tell us what you are **actually** trying to do or add.

Comment: `@OP` - Next time you post a question, make sure you **indent your code properly**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a long shot here and assume you're asking how to add more than one $subcategory_id.

In that case, I would setup your form element to name='termId[]' so you can have an array of values.

Then change the query to end with (I'm assuming you'd surround it with quotes:

' AND wp_terms.term_id IN ( '. implode(",",$subcategory_id) . ' )';

Otherwise you could just add multiple AND clauses to your query. i.e.

AND wp_terms.term_id = '$variable'

Answer (score 0):

Using the MySql function implode record will store into the DB with comma separated format. Need to keep this DB field type in varchar.